# Babel: replaceWithSourceString giving Unexpected token (1:1)

Tags: plugins, build, babeljs, middleware

I am trying to replace dynamically "import" statements.

Here is an example that checks if the import ends with a Plus.

```
module.exports = function(babel) {

    return {
        visitor: {
            ImportDeclaration: function(path, state) {
             // import abc from "./logic/+"
             if( ! path.node.source.value.endsWith("/+"))
              return;

             path.replaceWithSourceString('import all from "./logic/all"')

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error of

```
SyntaxError: src/boom.js: Unexpected token (1:1) - make sure this is an expression.
> 1 | (import all from "./logic/all")
```

The problem is that [replaceWithSourceString is wrapping the string in rounded braces.](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eac4c5bc17133c2857f2c94c1a6a8643e3b547a7/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/replacement.js#L75)

If I change the replaceWithSourceString to

```
path.replaceWithSourceString('console.log("Hi")')
```

and this works.. **¯_(ツ)_/¯**

Any and all help you be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceWithSourceString` should really be avoided, because it is just not a very good API, as you are seeing. The recommended approach for creating ASTs to insert into the script is to use [`template`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-template). Assuming this is for Babel 7.x, you can do

```
const importNode = babel.template.statement.ast`import all from "./logic/all"`;
path.replaceWith(importNode);
```

Comment: Is this possible with Babel standalone? template doesn't seem to be available in version 7.12.9

Comment: @cbutler Are you pulling `babel` from the first param of the plugin function like the OP is? It should be available there for standalone too I'd expect.

Comment: My code is a bit different than the OP. I could add it as an answer here but someone would probably yell at me for that or I could create a new question. But when I check Babel in the console it is not on the Babel object

Comment: I created my own question here is anyone is keen to help (would be greatly appreciated) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727830/babel-plugin-error-dont-use-path-replacewith-with-a-source-string-use-pa